# .NET async/await: in this case should I return something?

Tags: c#, async-await

In a case like this, where my task could return instantly because of certain conditions:

```
public async Task Test(List<int> TestList)
{
    if (TestList.Count() == 0)
        return;

    // Do something
    await UploadListAsync(TestList);
}
```

Is it correct `return;`, should I use `Task.FromResult(false);`, or is there a more correct way?

Comment: Just a return is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you're using an `async`, you can't return a `Task` explicitly (see edit) - the return value has been boxed up by the compiler to be the return value of the `Task`. Thus, your `async` methods should behave like other methods and `return` if they need to bail out of logic early.

**EDIT:**
The one time you CAN return a `Task` during an `async` is if the return type is `Task<Task...`, however this would still be returning the inner `Task`, not the outer, since the compiler has done the same wrapping. This should also be a fairly rare use case as opposed to `await`-ing a chain of `Task`s

Answer (score 0):

`Task` is the new `void`!

Regarding `async` methods!